# Count if with Date Criteria from Excel to SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, excel-formula

Formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,$A8,C:C,">="&C8-DAY(7),C:C,"<="&C8+DAY(7))
```

Can we convert above into SQL oracle syntax?

Basically, the formula is finding out count if a code is repeated within `T-7` days or  `T+7` days.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use an analytic function with a `RANGE`:

```sql
SELECT code,
       created_dttm,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         PARTITION BY code
         ORDER BY created_dttm
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '7' DAY FOLLOWING
       ) AS within_7_days
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY created_dttm;
```

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( code, created_dttm ) AS
SELECT 'CODE' || ( MOD( LEVEL , 4 ) ),
       SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL( LEVEL - 1, 'DAY' )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE  | CREATED_DTTM        | WITHIN_7_DAYS
> :---- | :------------------ | ------------:
> CODE0 | 2020-09-22 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE3 | 2020-09-23 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE2 | 2020-09-24 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE1 | 2020-09-25 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE0 | 2020-09-26 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE3 | 2020-09-27 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE2 | 2020-09-28 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE1 | 2020-09-29 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE0 | 2020-09-30 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE3 | 2020-10-01 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE2 | 2020-10-02 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE1 | 2020-10-03 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE0 | 2020-10-04 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE3 | 2020-10-05 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE2 | 2020-10-06 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE1 | 2020-10-07 12:59:20 |             3
> CODE0 | 2020-10-08 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE3 | 2020-10-09 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE2 | 2020-10-10 12:59:20 |             2
> CODE1 | 2020-10-11 12:59:20 |             2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07220a0fbc19c78d546faeb82f0c87ac)*